# Axis label with units to a power - use \left( and \right)?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, parentheses

I'm using Gnuplot to produce my figures and I typeset the axes and labels with LaTeX in the final document from the resulting .eps figure.

My question is regarding the axis label style. Say I have an axis showing the volume in nanometres cubed, the label is then "  V  (nm^3) "  (where the "3" is in superscript).

Should I be using \left( and \right)  parentheses when it is a unit indication and not a mathematical expression? Or should I go with normal ( ) which then does not completely "cover" the expression due to the "3" that is cubed?

I.e., should my label be typeset as

```
$V$ (\si{nm^3})
```

or

```
$V\, \left( \si{nm^3} \right)$
```

[image]

Edit: Changed the two above suggestions to reflect the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: It depends on the tradition in your field. In any case you should use the `siunitx` package to format the unit, do not do it by hand. Also in this case I would not use `\left...\right`, generally only use that construction when explicitly necessary, often it is better to scale manually.

Comment: With `siunitx` it would be `$V$ (\si{nm^3})`

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, in the second one the space is too big.

Comment: @samcarter I agree, changed to a `\,` space

Comment: There is no problem in the fact that the parentheses don't “cover” the full height. I'd say the opposite: in the second row of your picture, you can clearly see that the parentheses extend too much below the baseline for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, I will close this by answering to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments, for axis labels it is best to use the standard parenthesis, i.e. to use

```
$V$ (\si{nm^3})
```

and leave `\left(` and `\right)` for when doing mathematical expressions